# Why doesn't MSBuild create the folder to put the artifacts into?

Tags: msbuild

I maintain an old ASP.NET WebForms app written by someone who left 10+ years ago, long before I came here. I've migrated the project to GitHub. I'm using GitHub Actions, in conjunction with a GitHub Self-Hosted Runner on one of our servers. Here's the MSbuild line from the YAML:

`Run msbuild $env:Solution_Name /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=FP_Timetrack\FP_Timetrack\TimeTrackSite\bin\Release\Publish`

As you can see the intent is to publish the artifacts into FP_Timetrack\FP_Timetrack\TimeTrackSite\bin\Release\Publish. However, when I look at the relevant folder on the server where GitHub self-hosted runner is, there are no folders under the "bin" folder.

I've tried searching for answers to this problem, including here on SO, but that leads me to posts about ClickOnce deployments, which aren't pertinent to my situation.

So, what's preventing MSBuild from creating the Release\Publish folder under bin?

Comment: Does it work if you create the folders? (Not having used GitHub actions, I don't know if that's even something you can do). What if you can mkdir before the Run msbuild (or equivalent)?

Comment: I'm new to GitHub Actions, too. I don't know how to create the folder.